# C# Regex Find all string expect in debug string

Tags: c#, regex, regex-negation

First thing first, I can only use C# regex, so suggesting other languages or non-regex solution won't won't help. Now question.

I have to find all the string in code (couple of thousand file). There basically 6 cases:

```
   string a = "something"; // output" "something"
   sring b = "something else" + " more"; // output: "something else" and " more"
   Print("this should match"); // output: "this should match"
   Print("So" + "should this"); // output: "So" and "should this"
   Debug("just some bebug text"); // output: this should not match
   Debug("more " + "debug text"); // output: this should not match
```

The regex should match first 4 (I only need whats inside the quotes, and Print can be any other function as well)

So far I have this, which returns anything in quotes:

```
 ".*?"
```

Comment: I would suggest getting a regex tool to help you with your homework.  I use expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm).

Comment: Can you give some sample data? Or you just want to exclude any line with `"debug"`?

Comment: The output of the above should be: "something", "something else", " more",  "this should match", "So", "should this". What I don't want is "just some bebug text", "more " and "debug text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:** `@"^(?!Debug\("")([^""]*""(?<Text>[^""]*)"")*.*$"`

**What it does:**

- Doesn't match a string if it starts with `Debug("`
- Runs along the string until it meets the first `"`, and goes past it

  - If a `"` hasn't been found and it reached the end of the string, it will stop.
- Starts "Recording" into a group named `Text`
- Runs along the string until it meets the next `"`, stops recording, and goes past it.
- Returns to step 2

**Result:** You have all strings between `"`'s in a group called `Text`.

**Whats left for you to do:** Turn it into a multiline regex and support whitepsaces (`\s`) before the Debug as a better filter.

**Further usage example and testing:**

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^(?!Debug\("")([^""]*""(?<Text>[^""]*)"")*.*$");

var inputs = new[]
                 {
                     @"string a = ""something"";",
                     @"sring b = ""something else"" + "" more"";",
                     @"Print(""this should match"");",
                     @"Print(""So"" + ""should this"");",
                     @"Debug(""just some bebug text"");",
                     @"Debug(""more "" + ""debug text"");"
                 };

foreach (var input in inputs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    Console.WriteLine("=====");

    var match = regex.Match(input);

    var captures = match.Groups["Text"].Captures;

    for (var i = 0; i < captures.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(captures[i].Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("=====");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

**Output:**

```
string a = "something";
=====
something
=====

sring b = "something else" + " more";
=====
something else
 more
=====

Print("this should match");
=====
this should match
=====

Print("So" + "should this");
=====
So
should this
=====

Debug("just some bebug text");
=====
=====

Debug("more " + "debug text");
=====
=====
```

Comment: Regarding your comment, I misunderstood the question, so I will remove my answer. About "only regex" part, I will suggest any equivalently good solution that is simpler than regex, since he is coding the extraction program in C#.

Comment: @nhahtdh Totally agree, but `I can only use C# regex` - sounds like homework - nothing to do about it. These are the needs of the OP.

Comment: @YoryeNathan, thanks for the help. It works but I'm still having hard time breaking it down to how you got there. From what I understand, `^(?!Debug\(")` to get rid of `Debug("`. `([^"]*"(?<Text>[^"]*)")*` for actual strings, with `[^"]*` to get rid of `"` and then `.*$` to comsume `);` at the end of the line. I use [link](http://rubular.com/) to test when regex when I write one, and the above regex still doesn't work there. I assume ruby has different rules for regex?

Comment: `(?!Debug("` gets rid of lines starting with `Debug("`, but doesn't really "move the reader" - just makes sure that it doesn't start with it and then goes back to the beginning to try match the rest of the string. `[^"]*` is to pass all the non `"` characters, and then `"` is to consume the `"` the `"` character, so now we're in the beginning of a Text. `(?<Text>[^"]*)` consumes everything until the next `"` into the Text group, then another `"` to consume the `"`, and the whole last part in parenthesis and then `*` to allow more than one Text in that line (`*` is "repeat zero times or more").